# Use the system clipboard in vim instead of vim's clipboard

Tags: macos, vim, clipboard

Is there any way to use the system clipboard on Mac OS X (it is accessible with `pbpaste` and `pbcopy` to read and write, respectively) in place of vim's clipboard? So, for instance, when I did a cut or copy in vim, it would go to the system clipboard. And, also, if I copied something to the system clipboard, I could paste it into vim with <kbd>P</kbd> or <kbd>p</kbd>

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vim 7.3 added “clipboard support in the Mac console” (see under `:help added-7.3`). The standard `*` register is the system clipboard when running a tty-based instance of *vim* (`+` also works and is an alias for `*` like most non-X11 systems). I am using Vim 7.3 from MacPorts.

Paste: `"*p`
Copy 4 lines: `"*4yy`
Cut 4 lines: `"*4dd`

For Vim 7 versions before 7.3, you can use [fakeclip](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2098).

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks! But, is there any way to map it to a different shortcut?

Comment: You could map then to pretty much anything you want with various `map` commands. F1 as Paste: `:map! <F1> "*p` F2 as Copy: `:map! <F2> "*y` (press F2 then a motion command, or press F2 with a visual selection active). With the support built into Vim 7.3 you can also `:set clipboard=unnamed` so that normal yank, delete, change, and put operations (i.e. those done without a `"` + register character prefix) go through the system clipboard.